# Hive installation error : com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am new to hadoop, after installing Hive when I enter hive command in command prompt it giving me following error. Installed Hadoop version is 3.1.3. Derby is also installed with 10.12.1.1 version.

```
C:\apache-hive-2.1.0-bin\bin>hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl- 
2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/hadoop-3.1.3/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12- 
1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only 
errors to the console.
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://
com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
Beeline version 2.1.0 by Apache Hive
com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
Connection is already closed.

C:\apache-hive-2.1.0-bin\bin>
```